# "cp: Command not found" when recreating and extending centos6-i386 Docker base image

Tags: linux, gcc, docker, centos6

I'm currently rebuilding our build server, and creating a set of Docker images for our various projects, as each has rather different toolchain and library requirements. Since Docker currently only runs on 64-bit hosts, the build server will be a x86_64 Fedora 22 machine.

These images must be able to build historical/tagged releases of our projects without modification; we can make changes to the build process for each project if needed, but only for *current* trunk and *future* releases.

Now, one of my build environments needs to reproduce an old i686 build server. For executing 32-bit programs I can simply install i686 support libraries (`yum install glibc.i686 ncurses-libs.i686`), but that doesn't help me to *build* 32-bit programs, without having to modify Makefiles to pass `-m32` to GCC … and, as stated above, I do not wish to alter historical codebases at all.

So, my current idea is to basically fake a i686 version of CentOS in a Docker container by installing *all* i686 packages, including GCC. That way, although `uname -a` will report the host's x86_64 architecture, everything else within the container should be pretty consistent. I took the idea (and `centos6.tar.gz`) from [the "centos-i386" base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/toopher/centos-i386/~/dockerfile/) which, in essence, I'm trying to reproduce for my own local image.

Sadly, it's not going very well.

Here's a minimal-ish `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM scratch


# Inspiration from https://hub.docker.com/r/toopher/centos-i386/~/dockerfile/
ADD centos6.tar.gz /
RUN echo "i686" > /etc/yum/vars/arch && \
    echo "i386" > /etc/yum/vars/basearch
ENTRYPOINT ["linux32"]

# Base packages
RUN yum update -y && yum -y install epel-release patch sed subversion bzip zip

# AT91SAM9260 ARM compiler
ADD arm-2009q1-203-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2 /usr/local/
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/arm-2009q1/bin

# AT91SAM9260 & native cxxtest
ADD cxxtest-3.10.1.tar.gz /staging/
WORKDIR /staging/cxxtest/
RUN cp -r cxxtest /usr/local/arm-2009q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/
RUN cp -r cxxtest /usr/local/include/
RUN cp cxxtestgen.pl /usr/bin/
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/cxxtestgen.pl /usr/bin/cxxtestgen
WORKDIR /
RUN rm -rf /staging/
```

The build fails on the first "`RUN`" in the cxxtest installation step:

```
/bin/sh: cp: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c cp -r cxxtest /usr/local/arm-2009q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your image is being built from "scratch", not from the "centos6" base image (as is the case with the published "centos6-i686" image), even though you unpacked CentOS 6 into the filesystem as your first step, Bash was started up before that so your shell context has no meaningful `PATH` set. Adding the following after your "`ENTRYPOINT`" will result in all the usual binaries being accessible again, for the duration of the build process:

```
ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Containers created from your image (had it built; say, by not trying to build *cxxtest*) would never have been affected, as the fresh Bash instances would have had the PATH correctly set through `/etc/profile`.